# Non-monotonic decile averages

Tags: deciles

I've got a range of scores (output of a statistical model) between 0.0 and 1.0.

When I split these into deciles and take within-decile averages, I get a sequence of numbers that is **not** monotonically increasing from the bottom decile to the top. Am I crazy or should that not be possible?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example with this property? We may at least be able to tell you what the correct averages would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to CV.

That should not be possible. You've done something wrong; however, questions about coding are off topic here.

Comment: I'll nitpick here and say that this is, in fact, not a question about coding; I haven't specified whether my decile analysis was done by hand or not, and the source of the scores is irrelevant (to the meat of the question).

Nonetheless, thanks for the answer.